# Issue accessing sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a project in ASP.NET in which i would like the UI to add data that the user types in into a table in the sql database

I have set up the view and the SQL database. I would like some guidance regarding what c# code would be best to utilise in the controller to firstly add data user enters in the form of id numbers and user names into a SQL database and secondly perform a search on the id

I have been able to pull information fom my table in the sql server to my ui by using `dbentity db = new dbentity()` which will create a new instance of my database which contains my table.

And then using `var results = (from a in db.users orderby a.id select a)`.

My question is how do i add information to my table? when i have done that how do i run a loop to search for information in the table?

Hope this is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello here is a nice codeproject guide that can get you started with using a database in C#.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C

Cheers!

Comment: thanks JBurlison this is useful however i am still having problems implementing this. I have added further clarity to the question above